# how to update data from props to d3 function?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, updates, react-props

I am trying to update datas from props to d3, but the problem is whenever I call d3 function, computer will generate a new chart. is there a way to remove the previous chart before creating a new one? or how to update datas from props to startD3 function without it creates a new chart? thanks in advance

```
class WiningRate extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.startD3(this.props.data);
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps = () => {
        this.startD3(this.props.data);
    }

    startD3 = (data) => {...}

    render () {...}
}
```

Comment: depends on what `startD3` does: `d3.select("#chart").remove()` or `d3.select("svg").remove()` or `d3.select("svg").selectAll("*").remove()` or some other variation

Comment: if I use d3.select("svg").remove() then there will be a delay before it redraws a new chart. startD3 will create a chart

Comment: then remove the content of the `svg` where you are constructing the chart, don't add an `svg` if it is already there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I just move componentWillReceiveProps function inside startD3 function, I don't know if it is an acceptable practice or not though